# Xsetwacom Top and Bottom values for Wacom Bamboo Fun 6X8?

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

Does anybody know what are the Wacom Bamboo Fun CTH-661 correct values for BottomX/BottomY and TopX/TopY? I got the tablet to work under 10.10, but when I move the cursor over the edges of the screen, it jumps a lot...

Answer (score 2):

If the default values aren't correct then please report this as a bug here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bugs

To fix your issue right now, you could try trial and error until you get it working.